# Goodness of fit: what is Cramer-Von Mises statistics for copula

Tags: goodness-of-fit, notation, copula

I'm reading 'Goodness-of-fit tests for copulas: A review and a power study' Christian Genest(2009). The paper considers rank-based versions of Cramer-Von Mises statistics [image]

How is it possible for a discontinuous function be differentiated?

[Goodness-of-fit tests for copulas: A review and a power study](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0167668707001205/1-s2.0-S0167668707001205-main.pdf?_tid=69bfd3f0-32fb-11e7-9717-00000aab0f6b&acdnat=1494144285_b791b0de08d885e47e716e1d8f5c6719)

Comment: $dC_n(u)$ is empirical distribution function.  Also the cramer-von mises definition from wikipeidia which differentiate theoretical distribution is different from here.

Comment: This is a Riemann-Stieltjes integral:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral   So in this case, that integral is simply notation for a finite sum!